# How I can delete document in firebase that has the same user uid ? in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my code in React Native

```
const UserList = ({navigation})=>{

    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([]);
    const userLists = db.collection('users')
    const [deleted, setDeleted] = useState(false)


      {/*fetch all users from firestore function*/}

        const fetchData = async()=>{
            const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
    
                const list=[];
                if(user){
                 await userLists
               //  .orderBy('submitTime','desc')
                .get()
                .then((querySnapshot)=>{
                    querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
                        const {name, phone,email,address,userImg,} = doc.data()
                        list.push({
                          id:doc.id,
                          name: name,
                          email: email,
                          phone: phone,
                          address: address,
                          userImg:userImg
                            
                        
                        })
                        setUserData(list)
                    })
                    setUserData(list)
                })
                 } else{
                   setUserData(null)
               }  
        })
        return () => unsubscribe(); 
    }


        {/*Delete users function*/}

    const deleteUserById = async(id)=>{
        await db.collection('users').doc(id).delete()
        .then(()=>{
            setDeleted(true)
            Alert.alert(
                'DELETE USER ACCOUNT',
                'User Account has been deleted successfully'
            )
        })
        .catch(e => console.log('error'))
    }
```

so I could fetch and display all users from firestore 'users' collection and all users have been created by using .set() method which saved the users with the same user uid. so each user saved in firestore hold the same user uid. Now i'm trying to delete each document in users collection by user uid, any idea please let me know guys and thank you in advance

Comment: If `id` in this code is the UID of the user **and** that is the ID of the document with their profile too, then this code looks correct: `await db.collection('users').doc(id).delete()`. Is the value of `id` indeed the same as the document ID? What isn't working about it? Is there any error message?

Comment: well, there is no error message but the function doesn't delete the user but when I copy the uid of the document and paste in id the document is deleted. so how I can make the id in this code as the same of user uid? in addition, when I use id to delete the documents with random id the function is working but with documents with same user uid the  delete function is not working

Comment: There's no code *caling* `deleteUserById` in what you shared, so it's hard to say where the wrong ID value is coming from.

Comment: `<FlatList  data={userData} renderItem={({item})=>{<Swipeable renderRightActions={()=>deleteUserByI(item.id)}> <View><View><Image  source={images.donate_logo} resizeMode='contain' /><View><Text>User Name:</Text><Text>{item.nam}</Text></View>`

Comment: So it seems like `item.id` in the `deleteUserByI(item.id)` call does not identify the document you want to delete. Here again, we have no way of knowing what that value is. I strongly recommend locally debugging the problem. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** (not the *last* as you seem to have been doing so far) line that doesn't do what you expect it to do? That's the where the problematic value originates, so where you can start fixing it.

Comment: so I'm wondering , the same code I can delete any random document that not has the same user uid but document got the same user uid can't be deleted

Comment: There is nothing in the code you shared that would explain that difference in behavior.

Comment: that's why... I'm wondering I couldn't figure it out anyways I really appreciate your help and effort. thank so much. between I will do try to handle it and post the answer here myself